# SMTP requires secure connection webmail

Tags: c#, smtp

I have created a simple contact that form which will then send the information to an email that is based in webmail.

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.com")
            {
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password"),
                EnableSsl = true,
            };

            string message = "information";

            var addr = new MailAddress("email");

            smtpClient.Send(addr.Address, addr.Address, "Contact Information", message);
```

I keep getting a secure connection message. I'm not sure if this is related to the site running as an HTTP instead of https or if it is due to the way the credentials are being sent. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the **exact** error message?

Comment: Use default credentials instead of a username and password.  Windows will block connections using username and password.

Comment: @jdweng How do I set default credentials?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.usedefaultcredentials?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @jdweng I tried setting up the useDefaultCredentials to true, but its still returning the same message. Would you be able to write up an answer showing what I should be doing? Thank you!

Comment: You need to check with your email carrier website to find the smtp settings.  Port number 587 is only for secure email servers HTTPS.  The port number varies depending on the email carrier.